# Is there any way to record HTTP POST data in Result Tree in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I was looking for a way to record the data I'm POSTing from Jmeter.
With normal configuration, in result tree I can only see:

`POST data:
--ybHHpToxMguqjy2d0Z2xCHFZ_bPa77--`

In my specific case, I need to debug a REST service, so I need to see the actual body I'm sending down to the server.
I'm wondering if there is any property/ configuration suitable to do this...

Answer (score 0):

It tooks some time to find solution..

In order too see the data you are posting, you need to uncheck the "use multipart/form-data for POST"